# install4j: List of Checkboxes

Tags: list, checkbox, install4j

Is it possible to use a list of checkboxes in install4j? Something like this example:

[image]

We would prefer to use such a list of checkboxes instead of a simple multi selection list.

thx!
Frank

Answer (score 2):

You could use a configurable form and then adding Check box components for each of your options.

You could then iterate over them using something similar to:

`for (Object o : formEnvironment.getFormComponents()){
    FormComponent checkbox = (FormComponent)o;
    if(((JCheckBox)checkbox.getConfigurationObject()).isSelected()){
        do something here
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

Serban's solution is good for a small fixed number of options. If the number of options is large or dynamic, there is no such component in install4j.

You could write your own screen with using the check box list from [jide common layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm). A sample on how to get started, is available in the customCode sample project (see src/SampleScreen.java).

Comment: Thx, Ingo and Serban! Unfornunatelly we do not have a fixed number of options. So I have to take a look at the jide common layer or use a multi selection list.